# Using implicit class to override method

Tags: scala, type-conversion

My intention is to change the behaviour of the `==` method in `String` to call `equalsIgnoreCase`.

This code

```
implicit class LowerCase(s: String) {
      override def ==(that: LowerCase) = that.equalsIgnoreCase(this)
}
```

results in this error

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : MyClass.LowerCase
 required: String
      override def ==(that: String) = that.equalsIgnoreCase(this)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get errors? Does it behave differently from what you expect? What did you expect and what does it do in reality, how does it differ from what you expected?

Comment: Yes, added compiler error message

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case there is already such method in class scala compiler would not search for implicit conversion.

Note that your implementation is invalid, it should be:

```
implicit class LowerCase(val s: String) {
      def ==(that: LowerCase) = that.s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.s)
}
```

Note that it's still useless.

In case you want to use it as `Map`'s key you should specify type manually:

```
implicit class LowerCase(val s: String) {
      // Use `equals`, not `==`
  override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
    case t: LowerCase => t.s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.s)
    case _ => false
  }

  // Don't forget to override hashCode for Map and Set
  override lazy val hashCode = s.toLowerCase.hashCode

  override def toString() = s
}

scala> Set[LowerCase]("A", "a", "b")
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[LowerCase] = Set(A, b)
```

If you want to use this method with variables like this `"a" == "A"` you should use another method name:

```
implicit class LowerCase(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
      def ===(that: String) = s.equalsIgnoreCase(that)
}

scala> "a" === "A"
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Is there a way to override a class method implicitly, i.e. without extending and manually overriding the superclass' method?

Comment: There are still errors: remove `override`, and the constructor parameter needs to be a `val`. But even then it won't work, because of what you mentioned (Scala has no reason to search for an implicit conversion).

Comment: Thank you very much senia, @Jesper. Indeed, defining a new method is much cleaner.

Comment: @hanxue: Note that there is already a method `===` (and `=/=`) in `scalaz` (see [Scalaz cheat sheet](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scalaz-cheat-sheet)), and you could override it's behavior using `implicit object IgnoreCaseEqual extends new Equal[String] { def equal(s1: String, s2: String) = s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) }`, but you'll have to hide a default implementation like this: `import Scalaz.{stringInstance => _, _}`.

Comment: Thanks senia. Not using scalaz for this particular application because it is really simple. Your answer is exactly what I needed :)