# Implicit class for overriding String.toBoolean

Tags: scala, implicit

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699105/using-implicit-class-to-override-method) answer, but it did not help. Here's the implementation I have.

```
implicit class MyString(s: String) {
  override def toBoolean = s.trim.toLowerCase match {
    case "true" | "t" | "1" => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
[error]  found   : s.type (with underlying type String)
[error]  required: ?{def toBoolean: ?}
[error] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method augmentString in object Predef of type (x: String)scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
[error]  and method MyString in trait ImplicitsStartingWithS of type (s: String)foo.MyString
[error]  are possible conversion functions from s.type to ?{def toBoolean: ?}
[error]           case Some(s) => s.toBoolean
[error]                           ^
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that implicit conversions *can't* override methods in the type being converted from: if such a method exists, the compiler simply won't look for the implicit! There is a fork of Scala called Scala-Virtualized which does allow this (you'd define a method `infix_toBoolean(x: String)`), but I'd recommend against it for general usage: if you can't live without this feature check it out.

In this case, as @moem's answer says, the `toBoolean` isn't actually defined on `String`. As an alternative to simply giving a different name to your `toBoolean`, you can also explicitly hide `augmentString` in a class by defining something else with this name: `def augmentString = ???` or

```
class MyString(s: String) {
  def toBoolean = s.trim.toLowerCase match {
    case "true" | "t" | "1" => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

implicit def augmentString(s: String) = new MyString(s)
```

Of course, this loses all other methods provided by this implicit as well, but you can provide them in `MyString` (e.g. by extending `StringOps`).

Answer (score 1):

Other than the fact that `toBoolean` does not override anything, your implementation is fine. However, as the compiler error helpfully indicates, the name of your method clashes with the `toBoolean` method in the automatically imported [`StringOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps@toBoolean:Boolean) class in `Predef`. As a result, there is more than one implicit conversion that could be applied and the compiler cannot decide which one to use. This is why the error indicates that there is ambiguity. The solution is to name your method differently, so the following should work.

```
implicit class MyString(s: String) {
  def toBooleanAlt = s.trim.toLowerCase match {
    case "true" | "t" | "1" => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```