# Is there a way an implicit class can override a default implementation

Tags: scala, implicit

Say I define the following:

```
class A {
    def foo() = println("A::foo")
}

implicit class Wrapper(a: A) {
    def foo() = println("Wrapper::foo")
    def bar() = println("Wrapper::bar")
}

val a = new A
a.foo()
a.bar()
```

A::foo() is the method that is called. Is there any possible way an implicit class can override the default implementation in A?

Comment: If that were possible, how would the language prioritize?

Comment: The compiler will never go to an implicit if it doesn't have to. It's always the solution of last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a member method exists then compiler [would not search for implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20699229/5205022). If overriding with inheritance is not an option, you might consider "turning the tables" and create a [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3514279/5205022) like so

```
class A {
  def foo() = println("A::foo")
  def zar() = println("A::zar")
}

class Wrapper(val a: A) {
  def foo() = println("Wrapper::foo")
  def bar() = println("Wrapper::bar")
}

implicit def unwrap(wrapped: Wrapper): A = wrapped.a

val a = new Wrapper(new A)
a.zar()   // A::zar
a.foo()   // Wrapper::foo
a.bar()   // Wrapper::bar
```

Comment: Can you plz explain what does "implicit def unwrap(wrapped: Wrapper): A = wrapped.a" do?

Comment: @Salim It expands `a.zar()` into `unwrap(a).zar()`  because `Wrapper` does not have `zar` member but `A` does. This delegates all calls to `A` except for those methods provided in `Wrapper`, such as `foo`, which in effect enables us to "override" `A.foo`.

Comment: Thanks Mario. Appreciate it.